# Showing the quintessential logarithm property using the Maclaurin series of $\log$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, taylor-expansion, multinomial-theorem

For $-1\le x<1$, we have
$$\log(1-x) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{k}\\$$
Taking $a,b$ with $|a|,|b|<1$ and $(1-a)(1-b)\le2$, on the function side clearly we have
$$\log(1-a)+\log(1-b) = \log((1-a)(1-b)) = \log(1-(a+b-ab))$$
On the series side, dispensing with the negatives this becomes
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^{k}+b^k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(a+b-ab)^{k}}{k}$$
This feels decidedly less-obvious: in order for us to have equality, all the mixed terms should cancel when we expand the sum. I have tried using the multinomial theorem to write the RHS as a multi-sum and tried several things in that vein to no end. For instance, we would write the RHS as:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+k_3=k\\ k_i\ge 0}} \binom{k}{k_1,k_2,k_3} a^{k_1}b^{k_2}(-ab)^{k_3}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+k_3=k\\ k_i\ge 0}} \binom{k}{k_1,k_2,k_3} a^{k_1+k_3}b^{k_2+k_3}(-1)^{k_3}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(a^k+b^k+(-ab)^k+\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+k_3=k\\ k_i\ge 1}} \binom{k}{k_1,k_2,k_3} a^{k_1+k_3}b^{k_2+k_3}(-1)^{k_3}\right)$$
Then it would suffice to show
$$-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-ab)^k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+k_3=k\\ k_i\ge 1}} \binom{k}{k_1,k_2,k_3} a^{k-k_2}b^{k-k_1}(-1)^{k_3}\right),$$and factoring out $(ab)^k$ and simplifying leaves
$$\log(2)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+k_3=k\\ k_i\ge 1}} \binom{k}{k_1,k_2,k_3} a^{-k_2}b^{-k_1}(-1)^{k_3}\right),$$
but I cannot make progress here. Of course, the result is obvious if one uses the closed-form of the logarithm, but the point of this question is to avoid doing that.

Comment: Proof by 'infinite freshman's dream'?

Comment: It is advisable to use $\ln$ instead of $\log$ for the natural logarithm.

Comment: No, I am not a member of "Notation Police"... An alternative proposal : In front of such a question, just say : notation "log" is used for the *natural* logarithm. Explanation : I am more on the applied mathematics side, where notation "log" often implicitly means "decimal log". That's all...

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use [Lucas sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence).
It is defined as $\,V_n := a^n+b^n.\,$ Define the quantities $\,P:=a+b,$ $Q:=ab.\,$
Then the recursion is $\,V_{n+2} = P V_{n+1} - QV_n.\,$ This implies that $\,V_n\,$ is a polynomial in $\,P,Q.\,$ First,
define the sequence:

$$ S_{n,m} := {n+m-1 \choose m-1}\frac1{m} P^n(-Q)^m. \tag1 $$

Then, use a formula from [OEIS A034807](https://oeis.org/A034807) to get

$$ A_k := \frac{a^k+b^k}k = \frac{V_k}k = \frac{P^k}k +
   \sum_{j=1}^{k/2}S_{k-2j,j}. \tag2 $$

Use the binomial theorem on $\,(P-Q)^k\,$ to get

$$ B_k := \frac{(a+b-ab)^{k}}{k} = \frac{(P-Q)^k}{k}
  = \frac{P^k}k + \sum_{j=1}^k S_{k-j,j}. \tag3 $$

Notice that
\begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{k} &= 
   \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{P^k}k +
   \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^{k/2}S_{k-2j,j} \\
 &= -\log(1-P) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty S_{n,m}
 \tag4 \end{align*}

where $\,n = k-2j,\, m = j.\,$ Similarly,
\begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^\infty B_{k} &= 
   \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{P^k}k +
   \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^k S_{k-j,j} \\
 &= -\log(1-P) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty S_{n,m}
 \tag5 \end{align*}

where $\,n = k-j, m = j.\,$ Combine the two equations to get

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty B_{k}. $$

Comment: Sorry, I have been traveling for a while and haven't had time to look at this. Can you please clarify the 'same terms are summed' bit?

Comment: @Integrand Thanks for that comment! I have added more details.